# CommandInvokeationFailure: Gradle build failed

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

All of a sudden I am unable to generate APKs. I have been running into a series of different errors. It looks like something is wrong with my multi-dex. Any help with this is appreciate, thanks!

[image]

I tried to update my android support libraries and then I ran into another error

[image]